# how to change images size using range slider in javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

the proplem is i have diffrents images all presented by id in selected option
 the images from selected option ,
i want to change size any image that selected by range slider
anyone can help plz?

```js
var ranger = document.getElementById('ranger');
var image1 =  document.getElementById('image1');
var width = image1.width;
var height = image1.height;

ranger.onchange = function(){
    image1.width = width * (ranger.value / 1);
    image1.height = height * (ranger.value / 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select"    >
  <select onchange="$('#image1').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" id="select">
    <option value=''>  </option>
    <option value='0-0.png'>0-0</option>
    <option value='0-1.png'>0-1</option>
    <option value='0-2.png'>0-2</option>
    <option value='0-3.png'>0-3</option>
    <option value='0-4.png'>0-4</option>
    <option value='0-5.png'>0-5</option>
  
    



  </select>
</div>
<img id="image1" width="100 " height="200 "  >

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input id="ranger" type="range" min="1" max="5" value="0" step="1" class="slider" style="width: 500px"  >
</div>
```

Comment: You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: is it better now ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="setImage();">
  <option value="0-0.jpeg">0-0</option>
  <option value="0-1.jpeg">0-1</option>
  <option value="0-2.jpeg">0-2</option>
  <option value="0-3.jpeg">0-3</option>
  <option value="0-4.jpeg">0-4</option>
  <option value="0-5.jpeg">0-5</option>
</select>

<input id="mySlider" type="range" min="1" max="5" value="1" step="1" onchange="resizeImage();" style="width:500px;">

<div id="img-wrapper" style="width:200px; height:200px;">
  <img src="0-0.jpeg" alt="My Image!" id="myImage" style="width:100%; height:1005;" />
</div>
```

#### Javascript:

```
function setImage() {
  var e = document.getElementById('mySelect');
  document.getElementById('myImage').src = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
}

function resizeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById('img-wrapper'),
      ranger = document.getElementById('mySlider');
  image.style.width = 200*(mySlider.value / 1)+'px';
}
```

Note that (in this case), you do not need to set `width` *and* `height` - changing one will automatically update the other ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the height and width by usin .attr()

Html :

```
   <img id="image" src="image.jpg" width="100 " height="200 "  >
      <div class="slidecontainer">
      <input id="ranger" type="range" min="1" max="5" value="1" step="1" class="slider" style="width: 500px"  >
```

Script :

```
var width = $("#image").attr("width");
var height = $("#image").attr("height");
$("#ranger").change( function() {
  $("#image").attr("width",width * (ranger.value / 1))
  $("#image").attr("height",height * (ranger.value / 1) )
});
```

Comment: without to change the height and width in code you wrote it's work for one image but my point is that i have a lot of images and i want to give the same function for all images in selected option